# Combining different fees columns to create PivotTable income statement?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerquery, unpivot, m

I have a table which records revenue for each product, split into type of revenue: price, fees, tax etc.

[image: source data]

To analyze the data I'd like to build a PivotTable to show the revenue breakdown, e.g.:

[image: PivotTable]

So to build this PivotTable I need to somehow create an intermediate table of the following format so the PivotTable can be used:

[image: data for pivot table]

My question is, how do I create a PivotTable from the original table automatically without manually constructing the second table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps you have to do:

(1) Enter the data.

[image]

(2) Go to the `Data` tab and select `From Table/Range`.

[image]

(3) A new window will open up with the Query Editor. Here you need to go to the `Transform` tab, select the three columns you wish to `unpivot` and then click `Unpivot Columns`.

[image]

(4) The result will be the following (shown in the Query Editor)

[image]

(5) Now you can `Load` this data to the sheet using `Close & Load To...` on the `Home` tab

[image]

(6) Select the option to show the data in a pivot table and indicate where the pivot table should be placed before clicking `OK`

[image]

(7) The final result should look something like this once you have dragged the various field into the respective boxes: product and attribute into rows while values goes into the values box

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you! (p.s. I use Excel 2010 so had to download PowerQuery add-on from Microsoft to get this feature.)