# Copying multiple columns under each other in Excel

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, copy-paste

I have a dataset with daily mean temperatures for 1752-2016. However, these data are in matrix form:

[Excel worksheet printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghapB.png)

they need to be set together in 1 large column. Therefore, I'd like the following structure: 
Column 1: 31 times the year
Column 2: 31 times the day of the month
Column 3: corresponding mean daily temperature

[desired structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccMfM.png)

Can anyone body help me or suggest what I should do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't quite understand the required structure at the moment - would it make more sense to have another column for month or are you just looking at January?

Comment: Anyway it should be perfectly do-able with an INDEX formula, I will look at it later if no-one else does.

Comment: It seems to me that you are looking for `unpivot`. Here is an answer I posted not too long ago which can easily resolve the issue at hand for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47283811/combining-different-fees-columns-to-create-pivottable-income-statement/47286415#47286415

Comment: Yes try unpivot first - that is a better idea.