# Displaying rows based on column label in Excel for a Pivot Table

Tags: vba, excel

I'm facing the following problem. I have a very large excel sheet in the format attached as a picture. For reasons beyond my control the basic formatting of this sheet needs to be maintained as people with no skill want to be able to edit this.

However, I need to work with the content and as it is quite large, it is really unreadable. So what I wanted to do is to be able to find the tasks belonging to different departments and the different people. My approach was to create two  pivot tables where I want a dropdown list with either the department or the person to be able to filter on the tasks that that belong to each of them. I have found how to filter on a dropdown menu, however this is for column entries. What I want to do is to filter on the column labels and then display the tasks for which the column I selected is non empty.

I need some help on the direction in which I need to search for the answer to this problem as I'm currently lost in solutions that have nothing to do with this problem.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Just unpivot the above data using the following explanation: https://wessexbi.wordpress.com/2014/02/27/unpivot-nested-headings-with-power-query/ Afterwards, you can use the raw data whichever way you want to (including your suggested pivot table reports). Here is a somewhat related / similar solution I posted not too long ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47283811/combining-different-fees-columns-to-create-pivottable-income-statement/47286415#47286415 Still, let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Power Query** Excel 2010+ you can download and activate easily or by default in 2016 version. There you can keep this format for your users and a pivot table for control.

[image]